# MVC HTML5 EMAIL tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email required")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

From that I want the view to return

```
 <input type="email" value="" name="Email" id="Email" data-val-required="Email required" data-val="true">
```

and also option to use jquery.validate.unobtrusive on the email address without including a regx.

But by default the type="text" and I do not get email validation. I only get required field validation
What is the easiest way to do this?

html5.js
or  http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29  (I tried this it make the  type="email" but ignores by data Annotations so I miss out on my client side validation)

or just make a HTML helper

or can I just manually override the **type** and add  **data-val-email** to my class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set type of input generated by TextBoxFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267108/is-it-possible-to-set-type-of-input-generated-by-textboxfor)

Comment: @pavel I asked this 3 years ago.  1 year before the question in your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/15/adding-client-validation-to-dataannotations-datatype-attribute.aspx).

Comment: Ahhh I see now the code I read here makes sense too http://www.pagedesigners.co.nz/2011/02/asp-net-mvc-3-email-validation-with-unobtrusive-jquery-validation/ .   Anyway to change type="text" to type="email"