# Is it possible to set type of input generated by TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 TextBoxFor in a form and would like to use type="email" for easier input for at least some mobile devices but cannot find how to set it using TextBoxFor. Is this not easily possible?

In View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

In model

```
[StringLength(50)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

(Already using a data annotation to protect size constraint in DB)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC HTML5 EMAIL tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272869/mvc-html5-email-tag)

Comment: I asked separately because I did not care about the email validation that the answer on that question goes into while glazing over what was my root problem of getting an input of type email.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try to use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email" })
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703538.aspx (htmlAttributes)

Comment: Don't know why I wrote this off and didn't just try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're using it the wrong way.

Use EditorFor in View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
```

In model, add the `[DataType( DataType.EmailAddress )]` Data Annotations property:

```
[DataType( DataType.EmailAddress )]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `[DataType( DataType.EmailAddress )]` to the email property.

```
[DataType( DataType.EmailAddress )]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[StringLength(50)]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Try to add this. I think it works.